# Algebra of Combinations.

Tags: combinatorics

How many solutions are there to the equation
$$
x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4} = 28\ {\large ?}\qquad\mbox{if}\qquad
x_{1} \geq 3\,,\ x_{2} \geq 3\,,\ x_{3} \geq 5\ \mbox{and}\ x_{4} \geq 5.
$$
$x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4}$ *positive odd numbers*.

Comment: Have you tried transforming the $x_i$ to $y_i$ so that you get something like  $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=n$ for $y_i$ non-negative integers?

Comment: $\displaystyle 84$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Let $y_1=x_1-3,y_2=x_2-3,y_3=x_3-5,y_4=x_4-5$

$\implies\sum_{i=1}^4 y_i=12$

As $y_i$s are even, let $y_i=2z_i$ where integer $z_i\ge0$

$\implies\sum_{i=1}^4(2z_i)=12\iff\sum_{i=1}^4 z_i=6$

Comment: @Henry, Thanks for your observation

Comment: thanks for the answer. but why yi = 2zi? not yi = 2zi + 1 ?

Comment: @RamlanEffendi, As $y_i$s are all even

Comment: @all, thanks very much. i am understand.

Comment: once question again, How many solutions are there to the equation a+b+c=15, abc is integer, 100<abc<900

Comment: @RamlanEffendi, Why don't you put this as an independent question to invite even greater audience.

Comment: i cannot type this as an independent question. maybe something wrong. i will try again

Comment: every i put as an independent question, there is an error. like that : "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
• This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

Comment: help me please...

Comment: Finally, what is the answer ?. It must be a number.

Comment: @FelixMarin It is well-known and easy to see that it equals the number of ways to select $3$ (separating) cells in a strip of length $6+3$, that is ${9 \choose 3}$, but you have already found a way to this number. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
\sum_{x_{1}\ =\ 3 \atop x_{1}\ {\rm odd}}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{2}\ =\ 3 \atop x_{2}\ {\rm odd}}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{3}\ =\ 5 \atop x_{3}\ {\rm odd}}^{\infty}
\sum_{x_{4}\ =\ 5 \atop x_{4}\ {\rm odd}}^{\infty}
\delta_{x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3} + x_{4},28}}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{d\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\delta_{\pars{2a + 3} + \pars{2b + 3} + \pars{2c + 5} + \pars{2d + 5},28}
=\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{d\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\delta_{a + b + c + d,6}
\\[5mm]&=\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\sum_{c\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{d\ =\ 0}^{\infty}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{-a - b - c - d + 7}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{7}}\pars{\sum_{a\ =\ 0}^{\infty}z^{a}}^{4}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{7}}\,\pars{1 \over 1 - z}^{4}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\ \overbrace{%
\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1^{-}}{1 \over z^{7 - k}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}
^{\dsc{\delta_{k,6}}}\ =\ {-4 \choose 6}\pars{-1}^{6}
\\[5mm]&={-\bracks{-4} + 6 - 1 \choose 6}\pars{-1}^{6}={9 \choose 6}
={9 \times 8 \times 7 \over 3 \times 2}=\color{#66f}{\Large 84}
\end{align}

Comment: This is great! I think you may provide a link to your answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102148/what-are-some-elementary-results-number-theory-using-theorems-that-went-long-u) thread. :-)