# the implications of the four colour theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I just wanted to know if the 4 colour theorem has in anyway contributed to development of other proofs, ideas, etc in math? maybe graph theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied it in general topology to prove that each open subset of the plane can be partitioned into $n$ homeomorphic parts for each $n\ge 4$, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102148/what-are-some-elementary-results-number-theory-using-theorems-that-went-long-u/1112891#1112891) answer.